# How do I test if a function was called by pressing a button using vitest?

Tags: tdd, vitest

I'm still struggling with understanding vitest and documentation, but hope my question is answerable. What i work with is a svelte component which has a bunch of other stuff in it, but for this test case I want to test if a specific function is called when the button is pressed. I read about mocking and spy / spyOn but I dont quite understand how they work.

The code for the button is the following:

```
 <div class="saveLoad">
        <button data-testid="saveOnlineButton" class="save" title="Click, to save the preset online" on:click={() => savePreset(false)}>Save</button>
        <button data-testid="loadOnlineButton" class="load" title="Click, to load preset from server" on:click={() => showLoadDialog()}>Load</button>
</div>
```

What I want to do is the following: In my test code i want to test pressing the button and then seeing if the function was called. So far i have:

```
import {fireEvent, render, screen} from '@testing-library/svelte';
import konfigPage from '../src/routes/configuration/+page.svelte';
import savePreset from '../src/routes/configuration/+page.svelte';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom/extend-expect';

describe("testing if the configuration pages loades everything properly", () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        render(konfigPage);
    });

    it('calls the "savePreset" function, when the responding button is clicked', async () => {

        await fireEvent.click(screen.getByTestId("saveOnlineButton"));

        expect(savePreset).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

Running the test (as expected)  give me an error:

"TypeError: [Function Page$] is not a spy or a call to a spy!"

How do I implement a spy using vitest?
Thanks in advance!

I researched and read documentation and expected to understand it. I did not and im looking for help here now.